# Adding checkboxes to every api data in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am pretty new to this thing and I am working on a to-do list for that I want to have a checkbox in front of every data from API to check whether it's done or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   fetch('http://localhost:5001/list')
            .then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
                
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
                console.log(err);
            });
        function appendData(data) {
          var string = JSON.stringify(data)   //converting data into string
          var arr = JSON.parse(string)       //converting data String into json
           console.log(arr.rows)
           var x = arr.rows
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) //
                {
                  var div = document.createElement("div");
                  var box;
                  div.innerHTML = arr.rows[i].name + `<input type="checkbox" name= `+(arr.rows[i].name)
+`><label for = `+(arr.rows[i].name)+`></label><br>`;
                  mainContainer.appendChild(div); 
                  }//{}
            
           /* console.log(arr.rows[i].name)*/
        }


</script>
```

I also created a div but its not working

```
<div class="CheckBox" id="myData">
<input type="checkbox" id="v1" name="v1" value="Bike">
<label for="v1" ></label><br>
</div>
```

Can someone please help me to have a checkbox for every data I get from API
Thanks in advance

Comment: look what you get from that fetch, your appendData function looks right

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider use of the `<template>` html element. Using it allows you to specify the html of a section that will be repeated many times on a page. Items in a list are just *perfect* for such functionality.

Rather than a block of javascript that creates a string or series of elements that will hold your info, you copy a pre-defined block and update details as necessary.

Compare These Two:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
                  var box;
                  div.innerHTML = arr.rows[i].name + `<input type="checkbox" name= `+(arr.rows[i].name)
+`><label for = `+(arr.rows[i].name)+`></label><br>`;
                  mainContainer.appendChild(div);
```

And

```
<template id='itemTemplate'>
    <div class='CheckBox'>
        <label><span id='rowName'></span><input type='checkbox'></label>
    </div>
</template>
```

No comparison, right? Notice how much easier the second is to read.

Here's an example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
"use strict";
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt)
{
    populatePage(dummyData);
}

var dummyData =
{
    rows: [
            {name: "Have problem with programming"},
            {name: "Ask question at SO"},
            {name: "Read answers"},
            {name: "Make an answer as correct if any are"},
            {name: "Profit $$$$"}
        ]
};

function populatePage(data)
{
    data.rows.forEach( eachItemFunc );
    
    function eachItemFunc(item, index, collection)
    {
        var tgtItem = document.getElementById('itemTemplate');
        var newCopy = tgtItem.content.cloneNode(true);
        var nameTgtElem = newCopy.querySelector('#rowName');
        nameTgtElem.textContent = item.name;
        document.body.appendChild(newCopy);
    }
}
</script>
<template id='itemTemplate'>
    <div class='CheckBox'>
        <label><span id='rowName'></span><input type='checkbox'></label>
    </div>
</template>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```